# My method to find element by xpath using Contains text in try catch block is returning false

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Webdriver with Python
I have a method which checks if the project name on the webpage contains an expected value.
My method is returning false.  I was expecting it to return true.

I am using the following xpath to check if an element contains the project name

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[contains(text(), %s)]' % project_name)
```

E.g. project name value I am looking for is `LADEMO_IE_05_21_1510_18_31`

When i print the xpath the following output is returned in the console & it is 
there (5th row down).

```
project_name_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[contains(text(), %s)]' % project_name)

print project_name_element.text
```

The output is as follows:

```
JMeter_Reports_MegaOneCC

LAdemo

Sales Demo

Normal

LADEMO_IE_05_21_1510_18_31

LADEMO create a basic project test script - Selenium Webdriver/Python Automated test

LADEMO_IE_05_21_1510_20_44
```

My code snippet is below of the method and the Test Case which calls the method.

From Pages\admin.py

```
import datetime
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from Locators.locators import MainPageLocators
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element
from Locators.element import BasePageElement
from Pages.base import BasePage
#from Pages.administrationPage import AdministrationPage
import re

class AdministrationPage(BasePage):

def is_project_text_present2(self, project_name):
        try:
            project_name_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[contains(text(), %s)]' % project_name)
            print project_name_element.text
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        return project_name_element.text in project_name
```

TestCases\AdministrationPage_TestCase.py

```
import unittest
import time
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element
from Pages import login
from Pages import admin
import datetime

class AdministrationPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

def test_add_Project(self):
    print "*** test_add_project ***"
    #this var contains the project name value e.g. LADEMO_IE_05_20_152015 which is then used for project_name_textfield.send_keys(project_name_fieldValue) from the add_project method
    project_name = "LADEMO_IE_" + self.get_datetime_now()
    print "project_name_value" + project_name
    login_page = login.LoginPage(self.driver)
    login_page.userLogin_valid("riaz.ladhani", "pass123")
    administration_page = login_page.clickAdministration()
    administration_page.add_project(project_name)
    try:
        administration_page.is_project_text_present2(project_name)
        print administration_page.is_project_text_present2(project_name) # false is printed here on the console. I want this to be true because the project name text does exist
    except AssertionError as e:
        self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
    print "I am here in except AssertionError as e: administration_page.is_project_text_present2(project_name)"
```

The output to the console is

False
I am here in except AssertionError as e: 
administration_page.is_project_text_present2(project_name)

Is there something incorrect in my method to return false and not true?

The HTML is:

```
    <table cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr class="GAT4PNUFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <tr class="GAT4PNUEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
    <tr class="GAT4PNUFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
    <tr class="GAT4PNUEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
    <tr class="GAT4PNUFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="4">
    <tr class="GAT4PNUEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="5">
    <tr class="GAT4PNUFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="6">
    <tr class="GAT4PNUEH GAT4PNUMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="7">
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUHG GAT4PNUNG">
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-113" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="linkhover" title="LADEMO_IE_05_21_1510_18_31" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">LADEMO_IE_05_21_1510_18_31</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUNG">
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUNG">
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUBH GAT4PNUNG">
</tr>
<tr class="GAT4PNUFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="8">
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUHG">
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-113" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="linkhover" title="LADEMO_IE_05_21_1510_20_44" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">LADEMO_IE_05_21_1510_20_44</span>
        </div>
    </td>
        <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG">
       <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG">
       <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUBH">
     </tr>
     <tr class="GAT4PNUEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="9">
     <tr class="GAT4PNUFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="10">
     ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this now.  I changed the XPath to find the projet name within the table Span class cell.
It now returns true when it finds the project name of LADEMO_IE_05_21_1510_18_31

Here is my code snippet:

Pages\admin.py

```
    def is_project_name_present(self, project_name):
        try:
            test = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(@class, "linkhover")][text()= "%s"]' % project_name)
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        return project_name in test.text # Check if the project name is in the list of projects (list of projects is in the html table, /td class span
```

TestCases\AdministrationPage_TestCase.py

```
administration_page.is_project_name_present(project_name)
    assert administration_page.is_project_name_present(project_name), "project name " + project_name + "not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in the time delay that you have. I suppose that when you call `administration_page.add_project(project_name)` it may take some time to add the project and your next line `administration_page.is_project_text_present2(project_name)` will return false because page still not ready. When you try it in the console you always find it.
To verify this idea please add some waiting before `is_project_text_present2`method. If it will work I suggest to use waiting to the specific element approach.